# how to create the control in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm new to iphone programming. there are lot of basic controls in xcode which i can implement but i want to know how to create the control shown below in iphone.

It is not present in list of control objects in xcode

[image]

Comment: There is no such control provided with the iOS SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no default dropdown implementations available for iPhone. You can try to implement a [`UIPickerView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html) or [`UIActionSheet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) based on the requirement.

If you cannot modify your design, you can go ahead and implement your own dropdown implementation. Basically you need to have a button with the above image as background view and on tap of that you need to show a table view below that. Alternatively you can check this [custom dropdown list](http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/iphone-development/custom-dropdown-list/) and [this Drop Down Demo iOS.](https://github.com/raihan/Drop-Down-Demo-iOS)

Comment: i know how to create dropdown using UIPickerView and UIActionSheet but i want to create dropdown as shown in figure

Comment: @pradeep, In that case, the second part answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode does not provide this control.You can create custom control with a table view and Button.Show the table view when you click on it and hide it on again clicking on it.You can also add images on background for the same look.